# can i comparing landsat 7 and landsat 8 thermal band?

Tags: raster, landsat-8, landsat-7

can i comparing landsat 7 (band 6) and landsat 8 (band 10&11) thermal band? because landsat 8 only have 100m spatial resolution, so the output looks more general or blurr than landsat 7 thermal band. 
and what does mean TIRS band can be resampling to 30m resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the spectral ranges across sensors they seem quite comparable; TM5 10.40-12.50 µm, ETM+7 10.40-12.50 µm and TM8 10.60 - 11.19 µm or 11.50 - 12.51 µm. Depending on your statistical analysis, you may have to perform some data standardization but, this is often the case with comparing multi-temporal data.

Everything collected by TM5 and ETM+7 after Feb 25 2010 are resampled to 30m, otherwise are 60m. TM8 is resampled to 30m. This is done during post processing and I believe that they use a bilinear resampling method.

To understand the differences in spectra between sensors USGS developed the [Spectral Characteristics Viewer](http://landsat.usgs.gov/tools_spectralViewer.php). This may help you in deciding if the sensors are comparable for your specific application.